# difference between ad hoc and infrastructure wireless modes?

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, infrastructure

While creating wireless connection I get option to choose between  ad hoc and infrastructure mode.

[image]

Can someone explain the difference between them and which one should I use for my personal network?(I mean I do not wish to share it with anyone else)

Answer (score 1):

An Ad-hoc network allows devices to communicate directly without a central access point, e.g. a router. Only devices set up on the Ad-hoc network can communicate. An Infrastructure network allows devices to be connected via a central access point.
For home networking i would choose infrastructure if you are connected to a central access point, e.g. your router.